# Is the internal structure of a red-black-tree dependent on the insertion order?

Tags: data-structures, search-trees, red-black-trees

Is the internal structure of a red-black tree (which nodes are red or black, the disposition of the branches, the location of each value...) dependent on the order in which the elements were inserted? Or does it only depend on the *set* of inserted elements, without taking the order into account? Do different insertion orders always result in the same tree?

In case the order does indeed matter, is there an algorithm that, given a red-black tree, returns a sequence of elements such that inserting them in that same order gives back a tree structurally identical to the one with which we started?

**Edit:** As John L suggests in the comments, merely inserting two different values in different order already generates different trees.

And the question of finding a sequence of elements that results in the same tree is easy enough if we allow solutions of any complexity whatsoever. So let's say that we are interested in solutions of complexity equal or below   $O(n \times \log(n))$ where $n$ is the number of elements.

Also fix the algorithm to the one described in the paper [Red-Black Trees in a Functional Setting](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/chris-okasaki/redblack99.pdf) by Chris Okasaki.

Comment: Have you tried building a simple non-trivial red-black tree with different insertion order? For example, with key 1 and 2?

Comment: @JohnL. Different insertion orders can produce different trees indeed. My second question still stands though: is there some way of listing the elements in the tree so that we can then reconstruct a structurally identical tree?

Comment: You have to specify the algorithm that builds a red-black tree since given the same sequence of insertions, different algorithms can return different red-black trees.

Comment: Suppose the algorithm that has been to build red-black trees has been specified. Here is a naive solution. Just apply the algorithm to every permutation of the elements in the given red-black tree until it returns a red-black tree that is the structurally identical to the given one. You may want to add a requirement such as $O(n^2)$ or $O(n)$ time.

Comment: I'm not sure how to calculate the number of different valid RB-trees of the elements $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, but if it is asymptotically larger than $n!$, then a counting argument would give the answer "no" to your second question; namely that there is no injection $\{$rb-trees on 1 through n$\} \to S_n$

Comment: (I would think that it is larger than $n!$ due to extra choices with coloring